# How do I check (assert) if an Ember Promise is settled?

Tags: javascript, ember.js, promise, qunit

I have an Ember Promise returned as the result of a service method I am testing.  I'm using Ember 2.16 and qunit.

```
let promise = service.myFunctionBeingTested();
promise.then((resolveParam) => {
    assert.equal(resolveParam, EXPECTED_VAL);
}).catch(() => {
    assert.notOk("Promise rejected");
}

// Code here is supposed to trigger resolution of promise...

// Code here to make sure the promise is resolved and assert is run
```

What can I use (after the promise should be resolved) to make sure the promise ***is*** resolved and `assert.equal(resolveParam, EXPECTED_VAL);` is run?

It seems like it should be easy to check that the promise is settled, but Ember's documentation on rsvp promises is either too difficult to navigate or absent  I could use `assert.expect(/* COUNT */)` but then future users will have to update this number every time new assertions are added which I want to avoid.

Answer (score 3):

At the beginning of your test, use `assert.expect(1)` to tell the test you are expecting exactly 1 assert. Then you should be good. If the promise fails, your `notOk` will be called and the test will fail. If the promise resolves, the test will pass.

If this is not an acceptance test, you may need to:

```
import wait from 'ember-test-helpers/wait'
```

then return the wait call from your test to make sure the test waits for your promise before checking if it got the right number of assertions:

```
 return wait()
```

UPDATE

The other way you can do this without `assert.expect` is to declare a variable before like:

```
let successCalled = false
```

Then in the success block

```
promise.then((resolveParam) => {
    successCalled = true
})
```

Then after, do:

```
return wait().then(() => {
     assert.ok(successCalled)
})
```

Although, `assert.expect` exists for this purpose so I recommend using it.

Comment: I did mention in the question that I realized I could use assert.expect... I am hoping there is a property of the promise that can be checked so I can use a direct assert (for reasons mentioned in the question).